# What is the correct way to configure spring security to accept JSON based requests

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to figure out what the correct way to configure SpringSecurity is to receive, respond to json based authentication requests.

There appear to be two ways to do this :

1. Use the spring security configuration to route authentication requests to a Controller...see http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/implementing_ajax_authentication_using_jquery
2. Create a new AuthenticationFilter, AuthenticationSuccessHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler...see https://github.com/loiane/spring-security-extjs-login

It looks like the AuthenticationFilter method fits into the framework better, and ensures that filters that come afterward in the chain execute.

Anyone know what the pros/cons of either approach are?

Comment: Hi Karthik, I have similar question my self. It seems that creation of Authentication filter is much cleaner. 

What are your taught 's today regarding Controller vs Filter approach,  year after you posted this question?

Comment: I ended up going with AuthenticationFilter approach. that ensured that the rest of the filter chain was executed.  @svlada